# How to remotely control media playback?

Tags: windows, remote-control

My Wireless headset doesn't work on my 64Bit Win7. But luckily for me I have a backup 32Bit notebook, on this system the audio works fine. So what I was doing is plugging in this wireless device into the 32bit os, then connecting via rdc from the 64bit, and changing tracks like this - the only problem is that it takes long to load the rdc...

Is it possible to have a media player on the 64Bit machine, that plays tracks and controls the audio output of the 32Bit machine? without RDC or VNC, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both of these computers are running Windows 7, you can do this through Windows Media Player 12. ([Ars Technica link](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2008/10/hands-on-windows-media-player-12s-surprising-new-features.ars))

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked for Vista 64-bit drivers for your wireless headset?  Those should solve the original problem rather than forcing you to find a work-around.

Comment: Thanks Red for your answer, Unfortunately the device doesn't have drivers, but I figured out what the problem was - amazingly the graphics driver was causing the problem.